# Send a message to multiple chat ID in telegram group using python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram

Currently I'm working with my telegram python script and I want to modify it so I can send message to multiple chat id or telegram group using python script, as of now my script is working but can only read 1 chat id, can someone help me what I need to modify with my script? Thank you

**My script**

```
botToken = "somebot:ID"
chat_id = "someChatID1234"
```

Send data to telegram

```
print(files)
url='https://api.telegram.org/botsomeboy:ID/sendMessage?chat_id="&text="{}"'.format(files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this module :

[python-telegram-bot](https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram-bot/)